# Can you configure Phabricator/Arcanist to lint Java?

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

When I do `arc linters`, there are no options for a Java linter currently.  Is there a way to configure Arcanist to lint Java code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone built in this support but it has not been added into the core for one reason or another and likely will never be added into core. You can patch your version or arcanist or load in your own libphutil library.

https://secure.phabricator.com/D14632

The link above provides a linter for Java. If you want to load in the library and not fork arcanist here is the relevant [wiki page](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/). How to implement the above is another question however.